# How do I select a Random Row using NHibernate's ICriteria API?

Tags: nhibernate, random, icriteria

Can I select a random row using NHibernate's `ICriteria` API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just as cundh2o said, it's DBMS-specific. But you can subclass the Order class and define your own custom ordering. For example, for SQL Server:

```
public class RandomOrder: Order {
    public RandomOrder() : base("", true) {}
    public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        return new SqlString("newid()");
    }
}
```

Comment: 2.1.2 compatible: public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
        {
            return new SqlString("newid()");
        }

Comment: Use of Newid like this leads to terrible performance on medium-size to large tables though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited to using ICriteria, I might recommend using HQL instead for selecting a random row, since it may provide more flexibility to use the Random function supplied by your db provider.

```
IQuery q = NHibernateSession.CreateQuery("your hql statement here")
```