# NHibernate COALESCE

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to translate this sql-statement to a `CreateCriteria` and second does NHibernate deals with `ORDER BY COALESCE`?

```
SELECT obs1.OBSLOPNR, obs1.LOKALLOPNR, obs2.OBSLOPNR, obs2.LOKALLOPNR
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM OBS WHERE OBS.LOKALLOPNR = 9) AS obs1 
FULL OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM OBS WHERE OBS.LOKALLOPNR = 8) AS obs2 
ON obs1.ARTLOPNR = obs2.ARTLOPNR
ORDER BY COALESCE(obs1.OBSLOPNR, obs2.OBSLOPNR)
```

Comment: the situation like this we will always make it a store procedure, and then use session.getNameQuery() to call that procedure. Why don't we make things easy?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about CreateCriteria, but Hibernate/HQL supports COALESCE, IFNULL, or ISNULL Depending on your underlying database only in the Where Clause.

You may be able to define a function in the dialect and it should also work in the select clause. **I have not Tested This**

See: http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt support. You can however create your own Order class.
[Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729687/how-do-i-select-a-random-row-using-nhibernates-icriteria-api).

You could either create a class that accepts any string of sql, or you could try and create a CoalesceOrder class.