# When using CreateCriteria how do you sort the results in random order?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a function that returns a max number of items that are active.

I would like to be able to make the returned results be sorted in random order.

```
public IList<Widgets> GetWidgetsToDisplay(int maxToGet)
{
    var query = CommonSessionManager.GetSession().CreateCriteria<Widgets>()
        .Add(Expression.Eq("IsDeleted", false))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("IsActive", true));

    return query.SetMaxResults(maxToGet).List<Widgets>();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select a Random Row using NHibernate's ICriteria API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729687/how-do-i-select-a-random-row-using-nhibernates-icriteria-api)

Answer (score 1):

This will be database dependent but have a look [here](http://www.emadibrahim.com/2009/12/16/select-random-records-using-nhibernate/) for a sql server `order by newid()` solution.