# Select N Random Rows with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, random

How do I retrieve N random entities using Fluent NHibernate?

### Desired query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY newid()
```

I'd like to be able to use the Linq repo's for this, but I'm not sure if the result will be optimal. I am not familiar with HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SQL Server-specific Solution

Where `Word` is the random entity:

```
IQuery q = _unitOfWork.CurrentSession
                      .CreateQuery("from Word order by newid()")
                      .SetMaxResults(5);

var randomWords = q.List<Word>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Side note: FluentNHibernate is not for querying, it is for mapping and configuration only. Querying is part of "pure" NHibernate.

You can't do it using LINQ directly. The function `newid()` is SQL Server-specific, so there's no direct equivalent in NHibernate. What you can do here is to query using native SQL by using `ISession`'s `CreateSQLQuery` method.

See also here for more "deep into NHibernate" method:
[How do I select a Random Row using NHibernate's ICriteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729687/how-do-i-select-a-random-row-using-nhibernates-icriteria-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Take/Skip linq extensions:

```
var resultSet = session.Query<TestTable>().Skip(5).Take(10);
```

With PostgreSql DB this expands to the following SQL statement:

```
select TestTable.Id, TestTable.Field from TestTable
LIMIT :p0 OFFSET :p1;
```

Comment: That query pages, but does not select N **random** records.